# Linear regession problem

Tags: regression

I am doing a simple linear regression on SPSS and have run Spearman and Pearson tests which came out at .40's 
Now on the linear regression my B and bets have come out negative

I am not sure what to infer from this?

Amy help would be appreciated, I am only doing a short course in this so my background knowledge is not much

Comment: Oh, I have just figured it out, my scales go in different directions (at least I think that's what it is)

Comment: Thank you for making this a new question, @Apple. You can also add that comment as an 'official' answer, if it resolved your issue, and mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark that you will see to its left when you post the answer.

Comment: "bets"? are you talking about a standardized coefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note on regression betas and correlation coefficients. Just because two variables have a positive spearman/pearson, doesn't mean that the correlation will still be positive after controlling for other variables (which is what you're doing in a multivariate regression).

For example, let's say we calculate correlation coefficients of mother smoking during pregnancy V. birth weight of child and mother drinking coffee V. birth weight of child.

Let's say that coffee drinkers are more likely to be smokers.

Then if we estimate this model:
birth weight = beta1*smoking + beta2*coffee + error

Both correlation coefficients will probably be negative. However, we will probably find that beta1 is significantly negative, but beta2 is insignificant (i.e. it's not negative, but 0).

This means that the positive correlation sign for coffee was positive only because coffee drinkers are more likely to smoke and, therefore, have babies with low birth weights. If we control for smoking, we may see that coffee drinking has no effect at all on birth weight.